# Session cookie is removed after redirect method (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use an OpenID Connect library in PHP, I have downloaded and tested this one: https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

It worked perfectly, but then I started a Laravel 5.4 project and added the library to it. My idea is to use a middleware to redirect the user to the library and authenticate the user when the 'admin' page is requested.

But when the program reaches a 'redirect' method the session is lost, which didn't happen when I wasn't using Laravel.

This is the web.php file

```
    Route::group(['middlware' => 'web', 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('admin', 'KeycloakController@auth');

});
```

This is the kernel.php file

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \MiddlewareTest\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \MiddlewareTest\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],


          'auth' => [

            'keycloak' => \MiddlewareTest\Http\Middleware\Keycloak::class,
         ],
    ];
```

When the controller is reached, I call this method from another class

```
 private function requestAuthorization() {

        $auth_endpoint = $this->getProviderConfigValue("authorization_endpoint");
        $response_type = "code";

        // Generate and store a nonce in the session
        // The nonce is an arbitrary value
        $nonce = $this->generateRandString();
        Session::put('openid_connect_nonce', $nonce);

        // State essentially acts as a session key for OIDC
        $state = $this->generateRandString();
        Session::put('openid_connect_state', $state);


        Session::save();
        \Log::info(session('openid_connect_state'));

        $auth_params = array_merge($this->authParams, array(
            'response_type' => $response_type,
            'redirect_uri' => $this->getRedirectURL(),
            'client_id' => $this->clientID,
            'nonce' => $nonce,
            'state' => $state,
            'scope' => 'openid'
            ));

        // If the client has been registered with additional scopes
        if (sizeof($this->scopes) > 0) {
            $auth_params = array_merge($auth_params, array('scope' => implode(' ', $this->scopes)));
        }

        $auth_endpoint .= '?' . http_build_query($auth_params, null, '&');

        $this->redirect($auth_endpoint);

    }
```

But, when the browser goes to that URL in the 'redirect' method, the session is lost - I don't know why.

Please help me to understand why is this happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laravel doesn't use `PHP`'s native session so why you are using `$_SESSION` variable? You can use `Session::put('key', 'value')` to store the value into the session and `Session::get('key')` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thanks for asnwering, I am actually using `Session::put('key', 'value')` to store the values, I forgot to remove the `$_SESSION` variable from there.

Comment: the requestAuthorization is in controller or kernel

Comment: If you call method in controller construct, you session is not be there but in another method is fine.

Comment: Hi @AkkapongKajornwongwattana thanks for answering, the method is called in a function inside the controller.

Comment: in construct or not?

Comment: No, it is not in construct.

Comment: Why is this twice?
Session::put('openid_connect_nonce', $nonce);
$_SESSION['openid_connect_nonce'] = $nonce;

Comment: Hi @JuanJo I forgot to remove the native php session method because I tried to fill the session both ways, I have already commented the native way and it still doesn't work

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue, did you resolve it?